# adaptive payment paypal work with standard pay pal account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to user the adaptive payment paypal method for my website.

So for this we need use the pay-pal pro account or it working fine with  standard pay pal account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the following:

- A PayPal Business Account(Confirmed email and verified account) PRO account not required.
- Need to create a application at apps.paypal.com and submit(Adaptive Payment is a special feature which needs a application to be submitted and approved by app review team.

Once app is approved, you will be provided with APP ID which you can use in your API calls for adaptive Payment integration on your website.